# Unable to create a model in Rspec via Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a User in Rspec:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST #index" do
    it 'should create a user' do
      post :create, {name: "name1", age: 25}.to_json, format: :json
      # .............
```

But instead I get validation errors each time: `name can't be blank, age can't be blank`

The **UserController** accepts json:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params1)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


  def params1
    params.permit(:id, :name, :age)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters sent to `create` shouldn't be a json String but a Hash.

From the [rspec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec)  :

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe WidgetsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "responds to" do    
    it "responds to custom formats when provided in the params" do
      post :create, { :widget => { :name => "Any Name" }, :format => :json }
      expect(response.content_type).to eq "application/json"
    end
  end
end
```

So your test should be :

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST #create" do
    it 'should create a user' do
      post :create, { user: {name: "name1", age: 25}, :format => :json }
      ...
```