# Updating in Rspec isn't working, although the status is 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to update a User in Rspec:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "PUT #update" do
    it 'should update a user' do
        attr1 = { .............. }
        u1 = User.create!(attr1)
        put :update, { id: u1.to_param, user: attr1.merge({name: "name2", email: "email2@mail.com"}) }, format: :json
        u1.reload

        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
        expect(u1.name).to eq("name2")
```

The status is 200, but in the body the attributes that are returned aren't updated.

Comment: what do your logs say?  `log/test.log`

Comment: That the controller returns 200 tells you nothing. You can have a controller that does absolutely nothing and still returns 200. Please include the actual code under test.

Comment: Your controller of course.

Comment: @max the same as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568643/unable-to-create-a-model-in-rspec-via-post/41569446#41569446 but for update

Comment: When asked for supplementary information add it to the question itself. Don't expect people willing to help you to dig around, and don't make us guess...

Comment: @max, I will expect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are your attributes on attr, but try this:

```
describe "PUT #update" do
      let(:option) { assigns(:option) }

      before(:each) do
        attr1 = { .............. }
        u1 = create(:user, attr1....)
        put :update, params: {
          user: attributes_for(:user, name: "name2", email: "email2@mail.com"),
          id: u1.id
        }
      end

      it "should be success" do
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end

      it "should update attributes" do
        expect(u1.name).to "name2"
      end
    end
```